# Joi validation for a decimal number not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I am validating the request body for one of the API I am working on to insert the data in the DB. DB has precision as 3.

Below is the schema -

```
const insertDetails = {
  body: Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().length(6).required(),
    startdate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').required(),
    enddate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').required(),
    role: Joi.number().valid(5).required(),
    fnum: Joi.number().less(1.500).precision(3).required(),
    user: Joi.string().max(8).required()
  })
}
```

My understanding is for **fnum** that it'll only allow decimal precision upto 3 and should throw an error if there's a number like **1.345678** saying the precision should be 3.

But it goes through and while inserting the data , it rounds to 3 decimal places in the database.

I tried searching online and see that we can validate or set the convert to false but I am having difficulty doing it for just one of the field here i.e. **fnum**.

```
Joi.validate(insertDetails, {"convert": false})
```

I added above line but it throws an error saying

```
TypeError: Joi.validate is not a function
```

Any suggestions as to how can I validate the precision of the fnum in the request and should throw an error if the precision is more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define schema like this-

```
const insertSchema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().length(6).required(),
    startdate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').required(),
    enddate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').required(),
    role: Joi.number().valid(5).required(),
    fnum: Joi.number().less(1.500).precision(3).required(),
    user: Joi.string().max(8).required()
  })
```

Then Use the validate function with the schema-

```
const {error, value} = insertSchema.validate(req.body,{"convert": false});
```

You can place the `req.body` object as the first params and the next params will be options.

And this function will return an object with `error` and `value`.

---

Or you can create a middleware like this for routes-

```
const validateRequest = (
  req,
  next,
  schema,
  options = {
    abortEarly: false, // include all errors
    allowUnknown: true, // ignore unknown props
    stripUnknown: true, // remove unknown props
  },
) => {
  const { error, value } = schema.validate(req.body, options);
  if (error) {
    const error_ = new Error(`Validation error: ${error.details.map((x) => x.message).join(', ')}`);
    error_.statusCode = 400;
    throw error_;
  } else {
    req.body = value;
    next();
  }
};
```

Then create your schema with `validateRequest` function-

```
const insertSchema = (req, res, next) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
      id: Joi.string().length(6).required(),
      startdate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').required(),
      enddate: Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD').required(),
      role: Joi.number().valid(5).required(),
      fnum: Joi.number().less(1.5).precision(3).required(),
      user: Joi.string().max(8).required(),
    });
  validateRequest(req, next, schema);
};
```

Then use it in your router as a middleware-

```
router.post('/create-post', insertSchema, (req, res, next) => {
   // Do rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sahid. I believe the middleware option is what I am looking to do. Basically in options field, I have to add convert : false right? And when I call validateRequest, it should be something like this - validateRequest(req, next, insertSchema) ?

Comment: Sorry I was missing the schema variable inside `insertSchema ` funs. Just update my answer, please take a look!

Comment: And yes you have to pass `convert : false ` as an option in `validateRequest` func.

Comment: Getting an error -
```
_original: [Function: insertSchema],
  details: [
    {
      message: '"value" must be of type object',
      path: [],
      type: 'object.base',
      context: {
        type: 'object',
        label: 'value',
        value: [Function: insertSchema]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: One thing different here is I am using `express-validation`'s validate method in router.post. So it's something like validate(insertSchema) inside the API call.

Comment: If you are using `express-validation` then why you need `joi`. You can use one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238714/discussion-between-quicklearner-and-sahid-hossen).